# Why can I return the data from mongoose properly

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to get the data from mongoose.
Here is my code:

```
let data = [];
const getUserInfo = () => {
  UserInfo.find({}, function(err, docs){
      data = docs;
      console.log(data); //first log
  });
  console.log(data); //second log
};
getUserInfo();
```

The first log will print the right data, but the second log will return an empty set.
Why does that happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I read this article, change the getUserInfo to an async function and add the await syntax in front of the UserInfo.find(), but Mongoose will send me an error: "MongooseError: Query was already executed: UserInfo.find({})".

Comment: Also check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Answer (score 0):

You try this. Which gives you a simple layer and bug free code.

```js
let data = [];
const getUserInfo = async () => {
  data = await UserInfo.find();
  console.log("inside :", data);
  return; 
};
getUserInfo();

console.log("after :", data);
```

Comment: I had tried this, but mongoose sent this message to me "MongooseError: Query was already executed: UserInfo.find({})".